# After creating a method in c++ when calling it i'm getting error identifier not found

Tags: c++, visual-c++

This is the method

```
void SaveVideoToFile(int hr)
{

    IBaseFilter *pMux;
    hr = pCapBuilder->SetOutputFileName(
        &MEDIASUBTYPE_Avi,  // Specifies AVI for the target file.
        L"E:\\Example.avi", // File name.
        &pMux,              // Receives a pointer to the mux.
        NULL);

    hr = pCapBuilder->RenderStream(
        &PIN_CATEGORY_CAPTURE, // Pin category.
        &MEDIATYPE_Video,      // Media type.
        pCapFilter,                  // Capture filter.
        NULL,                  // Intermediate filter (optional).
        pMux);                 // Mux or file sink filter.

                               // Release the mux filter.
    pMux->Release();

    IConfigAviMux *pConfigMux = NULL;
    hr = pMux->QueryInterface(IID_IConfigAviMux, (void**)&pConfigMux);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        pConfigMux->SetMasterStream(1);
        pConfigMux->Release();
    }

    IConfigInterleaving *pInterleave = NULL;
    hr = pMux->QueryInterface(IID_IConfigInterleaving, (void**)&pInterleave);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        pInterleave->put_Mode(INTERLEAVE_CAPTURE);
        pInterleave->Release();
    }

    IBaseFilter *pEncoder;
    //Create the encoder filter (not shown).
    // Add it to the filter graph.
    pFilterGraph->AddFilter(pEncoder, L"Encoder");

    //Call SetOutputFileName as shown previously.

    // Render the stream.
    hr = pCapBuilder->RenderStream(&PIN_CATEGORY_CAPTURE, &MEDIATYPE_Video,
    pCapFilter,
    pEncoder, pMux);
    pEncoder->Release();
}
```

Added the method to the bottom of the cpp file.
Then when calling it I'm getting the error on the line:

```
SaveVideoToFile(hr);
```

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error C3861   'SaveVideoToFile': identifier not found

Comment: Did you remember to add a declaration to the header file?

Comment: Nathan no. I'm not so good yet in c++. I know there is cpp file and h file. Should I add a declaration of the method also in the h file ?

Comment: If you have a header file the declares everything that is in the cpp file then yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said you added the method to the bottom of the cpp file.

You have to declare or define identifiers to use *before* using them, so try adding prototype declaration `void SaveVideoToFile(int hr);` before where the function is used.